# Can I use my Android tablet to burn a new copy of Raspian?

Tags: raspbian, sd-card

Is it possible to use etcher or something similar to get a new copy of Raspian? The tablet has a USB port and the capability to copy it to my SD card reader. I only have my RPi3 and tablet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your Android tablet is rooted, you can (try to) install BusyBox. (For example using [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=stericson.busybox)).

Otherwise, no.

Comment: Even if your Android device is rooted, flashing a 1GB image might be awfully slow, depending on how your internal mSD card writer hardware has been wired up into the overall tablet hardware. Despite fast mSD cards, you may experience abysmal write performance which has its root (sorry for the pun) in the mSD card writer hardware.